# Spring: Multiple Cache Managers

Tags: spring, caching, ehcache, jhipster

I have a problem implementing a second cache manager. At the moment I'm using EhCache, which is working fine. Additionally, I would like to implement Java Simple Cache.

My `CacheConfiguration` looks like this:

CacheConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
@AutoConfigureAfter(value = { MetricsConfiguration.class })
@AutoConfigureBefore(value = { WebConfigurer.class, DatabaseConfiguration.class })
public class CacheConfiguration {

    private final javax.cache.configuration.Configuration<Object, Object> jcacheConfiguration;

    public CacheConfiguration(JHipsterProperties jHipsterProperties) {
        JHipsterProperties.Cache.Ehcache ehcache =
            jHipsterProperties.getCache().getEhcache();

        jcacheConfiguration = Eh107Configuration.fromEhcacheCacheConfiguration(
            CacheConfigurationBuilder.newCacheConfigurationBuilder(Object.class, Object.class,
                ResourcePoolsBuilder.heap(ehcache.getMaxEntries()))
                .withExpiry(Expirations.timeToLiveExpiration(Duration.of(ehcache.getTimeToLiveSeconds(), TimeUnit.SECONDS)))
                .build());
    }

    /**
     * EhCache configuration
     * 
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public JCacheManagerCustomizer cacheManagerCustomizer() {
        return cm -> {          
            cm.createCache(com.david.coinlender.domain.News.class.getName(), jcacheConfiguration);
            
    // ...More caches
    }
    
    /**
     * Java Simple Cache configuration
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    @Qualifier("simpleCacheManager")
    public CacheManager simpleCacheManager() {
        
        SimpleCacheManager simpleCacheManager = new SimpleCacheManager();       
        simpleCacheManager.setCaches(Arrays.asList(new ConcurrentMapCache("bitfinexAuthCache")));
        
        return simpleCacheManager;
        
    }
}
```

With Simple Cache I want to cache objects. I.e.:

```
@Cacheable(cacheManager = "simpleCacheManager", cacheNames = "bitfinexAuthCache", key = "#apiKey.apiKey")
private Exchange createBitfinexAuthenticatedExchange(ApiKeys apiKey) {
    
    ExchangeSpecification exSpec = new BitfinexExchange().getDefaultExchangeSpecification();
    exSpec.setApiKey(apiKey.getApiKey());
    exSpec.setSecretKey(apiKey.getSecret());
    
    Exchange bfx = ExchangeFactory.INSTANCE.createExchange(BitfinexExchange.class.getName());
    bfx.applySpecification(exSpec);
    
    return bfx;
}
```

However, on Server startup liquibase gives me an error stating:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: All Hibernate caches should be created upfront. Please update CacheConfiguration.java to add com.david.coinlender.domain.News
at io.github.jhipster.config.jcache.NoDefaultJCacheRegionFactory.createCache(NoDefaultJCacheRegionFactory.java:37)
at org.hibernate.cache.jcache.JCacheRegionFactory.getOrCreateCache(JCacheRegionFactory.java:190)
at org.hibernate.cache.jcache.JCacheRegionFactory.buildEntityRegion(JCacheRegionFactory.java:113)
at org.hibernate.cache.spi.RegionFactory.buildEntityRegion(RegionFactory.java:132)
at org.hibernate.internal.CacheImpl.determineEntityRegionAccessStrategy(CacheImpl.java:439)
at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.initialize(MetamodelImpl.java:120)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:297)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:445)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:889)
... 25 common frames omitted
```

I'm using the Jhipster framework for my appication. I googled this issue for hours now and haven't found a solution yet.

Is this error due to wrong configuration? Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: try `@Bean("simpleCacheManager")` instead of `@Qualifier`

Comment: Unfortunately throws the same error :/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In JHipster (I did the code), there is in fact two layers of cache. You have Spring Cache and Hibernate Second Level Cache. Both are using the same actual Ehcache `CacheManager`.

In your case, you've replaced Ehcache with a simple cache for Spring. But since the `NoDefaultJCacheRegionFactory` is still configured on Hibernate, it is still Ehcache that is used for Hibernate. But the customizer isn't used anymore. So it fails.

You would like to have a simple cache for Spring and Ehcache for Hibernate. This means that in fact to don't need to have bean registered for Ehcache in Spring.

The easiest is then to do the following.

First, configure Ehcache in `DatabaseConfiguration`. So when the hibernate JCache factory will retrieve it, it will be correctly configured.

```
public DatabaseConfiguration(Environment env, JHipsterProperties jHipsterProperties) {
    this.env = env;

    JHipsterProperties.Cache.Ehcache ehcache =
        jHipsterProperties.getCache().getEhcache();

    CachingProvider provider = Caching.getCachingProvider();
    javax.cache.CacheManager cacheManager = provider.getCacheManager();

    javax.cache.configuration.Configuration<Object, Object> jcacheConfiguration = Eh107Configuration.fromEhcacheCacheConfiguration(
        CacheConfigurationBuilder.newCacheConfigurationBuilder(Object.class, Object.class,
            ResourcePoolsBuilder.heap(ehcache.getMaxEntries()))
            .withExpiry(Expirations.timeToLiveExpiration(Duration.of(ehcache.getTimeToLiveSeconds(), TimeUnit.SECONDS)))
            .build());

    cacheManager.createCache(com.mycompany.myapp.domain.User.class.getName(), jcacheConfiguration);
    cacheManager.createCache(com.mycompany.myapp.domain.Authority.class.getName(), jcacheConfiguration);
    cacheManager.createCache(com.mycompany.myapp.domain.User.class.getName() + ".authorities", jcacheConfiguration);
}
```

Then, configure Spring Cache.

```
public class CacheConfiguration {

    public CacheConfiguration() {
    }

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        SimpleCacheManager cacheManager = new SimpleCacheManager();
        Collection<Cache> caches = Arrays.asList(
            new ConcurrentMapCache("mycache")
            // ...
        ); 
        cacheManager.setCaches(caches);
        return cacheManager;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I see that this is more complicated than I first thought. I wil try @Daniel C's suggestion in the next days and give you feedback.

Comment: I actually would like to implement two Cache Managers. For "standard" hibernate second level caching I would like to use EhCache (marked as @Primary). But for some use cases I need an implementation of Java Simple Cache (for Instance I want to cache objects which come back from an API - kind of a connection/exchange object). 
So as far as I understand it's not possible to just implement a second Cache in the CacheConfiguration.java?

Comment: Ah! This is different. It means you don't need to expose Ehcache from Spring then. Just need to configure the provider. And then expose the simple cache. Let me update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

[@EnableCaching Doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/EnableCaching.html)

> For those that wish to establish a more direct relationship between @EnableCaching and the exact cache manager bean to be used, the CachingConfigurer callback interface may be implemented. Notice the @Override-annotated methods below:

There is an additional alternative using `CachingConfigurer` and taking the approach that is implemented on [JCacheCacheConfiguration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/25f0b3482c59c26b9dc266dc0a1073a8a12dde65/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/cache/JCacheCacheConfiguration.java).

1- Implements the `CachingConfigurer` interface in `CacheConfiguration` class.  One option is extends from `JCacheConfigurerSupport`.

```
public class CustomCacheConfiguration extends JCacheConfigurerSupport {
```

2- Create the default `cacheManager` bean, since the bean is configured through `CachingConfigurer` it will be retrieved as a default `cacheManager` and in this case it can be used by hibernate second level cache, for this approach the `cacheManagerCustomizer` will be only a method.  Like this :

```
   @Bean
    @Override
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        javax.cache.CacheManager jCacheCacheManager = createCacheManager();
        cacheManagerCustomizer().customize(jCacheCacheManager);
        return new JCacheCacheManager(jCacheCacheManager);
    }

    private javax.cache.CacheManager createCacheManager()  {
        CachingProvider cachingProvider = Caching.getCachingProvider();
        return cachingProvider.getCacheManager();
    }

    private JCacheManagerCustomizer cacheManagerCustomizer() {
        return cm -> {

            cm.createCache(org.demo.app.domain.User.class.getName(), jcacheConfiguration);
        ......

      };
}
```

3- Create the `simpleCacheManager` bean

```
@Bean("simpleCacheManager")
    public SimpleCacheManager simpleCacheManager() {
        SimpleCacheManager simpleCacheManager = new SimpleCacheManager();
        simpleCacheManager.setCaches(Arrays.asList(new ConcurrentMapCache("bitfinexAuthCache")));

        return simpleCacheManager;

    }
```

4. In order to define which `cacheManager` will be used then define it through `@Cacheable(cacheManager = "simpleCacheManager", cacheNames = "bitfinexAuthCache")`

Here is the complete customization of `CacheConfiguration`.

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
@AutoConfigureAfter(value = { MetricsConfiguration.class })
@AutoConfigureBefore(value = { WebConfigurer.class, DatabaseConfiguration.class})
public class CacheConfiguration extends JCacheConfigurerSupport {

    private final javax.cache.configuration.Configuration<Object, Object> jcacheConfiguration;


    public CustomCacheConfiguration(JHipsterProperties jHipsterProperties) {
        JHipsterProperties.Cache.Ehcache ehcache =
            jHipsterProperties.getCache().getEhcache();




        jcacheConfiguration = Eh107Configuration.fromEhcacheCacheConfiguration(
            CacheConfigurationBuilder.newCacheConfigurationBuilder(Object.class, Object.class,
                ResourcePoolsBuilder.heap(ehcache.getMaxEntries()))
                .withExpiry(Expirations.timeToLiveExpiration(Duration.of(ehcache.getTimeToLiveSeconds(), TimeUnit.SECONDS)))
                .build());
    }


    @Bean
    @Override
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        javax.cache.CacheManager jCacheCacheManager = createCacheManager();
        cacheManagerCustomizer().customize(jCacheCacheManager);
        return new JCacheCacheManager(jCacheCacheManager);
    }

    private javax.cache.CacheManager createCacheManager()  {
        CachingProvider cachingProvider = Caching.getCachingProvider();
        return cachingProvider.getCacheManager();
    }


    private JCacheManagerCustomizer cacheManagerCustomizer() {
        return cm -> {

            cm.createCache(org.demo.app.domain.User.class.getName(), jcacheConfiguration);
            cm.createCache(org.demo.app.domain.Authority.class.getName(), jcacheConfiguration);
            cm.createCache(org.demo.app.domain.User.class.getName() + ".authorities", jcacheConfiguration);
            cm.createCache(org.demo.app.domain.Company.class.getName(), jcacheConfiguration);
            //cm.createCache(org.demo.app.domain.News.class.getName(), jcacheConfiguration);

        };
    }

    @Bean("simpleCacheManager")
    public SimpleCacheManager simpleCacheManager() {
        SimpleCacheManager simpleCacheManager = new SimpleCacheManager();
        simpleCacheManager.setCaches(Arrays.asList(new ConcurrentMapCache("bitfinexAuthCache")));

        return simpleCacheManager;

    }

}
```

Comment: No. The `NoDefaultJCacheRegionFactory` extends `JCacheRegionFactory`. Doing what you said will work but you won't get the cache you think.

Comment: Your are right!!, the `simpleCacheManager` is overwritting the default `jCacheCacheManager`, as soon as I create the `simpleCacheManager` bean the default cache manager is gone.  I was so wrong, thanks for your comments.  I will try again.

Comment: Hi @Henri, I added a new alternative based on `CachingConfigurer` interface.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. I will try that solution in the next days and give you feedback!